# Is it too expensive to run a CCSpawn of a CCRotateBy and CCBezierTo action?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I am trying to run a CCSpawn of a CCRotateBy and CCBezierTo action like so:

```
ccBezierConfig bezier;
    bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp (startX, startY);
    bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp (endX, endY);
    bezier.endPosition    = ccp (endX, endY);

    id rotate =[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:3.0f angle:360];
    id curve = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:3.0f bezier:bezier];
    id spawn = [CCSpawn actions:rotate, curve, nil];

    [self runAction:spawn];
```

but it seems to be pretty jerky/jumpy when these actions are running. I have tested it in the simulator (although that is not accurate) it is very jumpy on there, but then I am testing on an iphone 3gs, iphone 4, and iphone 5. The actions seem really smooth on the iphone 5 then it gets a little jerky one the iphone 4 and even more so on the 3gs. The problem I am having is I am not noticing any frame rate drop on any device or the simulator. Any insite would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: they are pretty fast, of course it depends on the definition of expensive, but i really would not be bothered by that. the bigger overhead there would be probably the cocos2d action scheduler himself,  not the type of action you are running. My advice would be dont loose time on that, you will probably have bottlenecks somewhere else

Comment: @Ultrakorne What about the jumpiness of the actions?

Comment: do not use simulator for any performance related stuff, it's always laggy. on the iphone4 it seems very strange that the action is not smooth, are you also running other stuff?

Comment: @Ultrakorne It is pretty noticable on the iphone 3gs also.

Comment: Try rebooting the device to avoid any "background" tasks interfering. Verify performance in **release** builds.

Comment: You should also make sure that you aren't sending any logging messages to the console (NSLog / CCLOG)

Comment: Are you trying to use actions and a physics engine at the same time?

Comment: @Mark Yes I was at the beginning but then I thought that maybe it was the physics causing the problem so I started a new cocos2d project and created the same actions and ran them on a single ccsprite and still got the same result. So my conclusion was that those actions must not be very optimized.